# android: how to assign value to a global variable from sql query?

Tags: android, global-variables, sql

i'd like to assign the resulting "reason" to a global variable for use with another process.  How can i achieve this from this declaration and function?

```
private static String[] FROM = { _ID, EVENT01, EVENT02, EVENT03, REASON};
private static String ORDER_BY = EVENT01;

private Cursor getEvent() {
    return managedQuery(CONTENT_URI, FROM, null, null, ORDER_BY);
}
```

many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Cursor, then iterate it and access the value

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
      //access the value using getString(0), or getInt(0)
}
```

U need to store this global, I think its better to use static variable,

```
class Abc {
        public static final String staticString;
        ----------------
        ----------------
}
```

Then you can access it anywhere using `Abc.staticString`
And its always better to create you Cursor inside a method and close it there itself, after its use.

Answer (score 0):

Another process or thread?

*For another process:* If you have ContentProvider you can get Cursor from others processes.